# Making a stainless steel tank for a copper pipe solar hot water system

Tags: water

I have a solar hot water system using copper pipework, which had a copper header tank, this leaks, and cannot be replaced. I would like to know if it is reasonable to build a stainless steel tank, say 1 mm thick? The water pressure is only max 3 atmospheres,

If so, is 1mm thick OK? The tank is 900mm long by 450mm diameter and would have flat ends.

Which is the grade of stainless steel to use, bearing in mind that the system uses copper pipes? The water is from a well very hard, but with very little chlorine.

Comment: Do you know the reason the copper tank started leaking?  If going to use different metals, usually need a way to keep them apart.  Usually dielectric fittings.  Hard water when heated and left sitting in a tank usually has a lot of settlement, that can plug up filters and pipes, if not drained/cleaned out every so often.

Comment: A rectangular tank will significantly distort with such thin material as 1mm. A round tank with hemispherical ends would work.  Think of it as similar to a balloon. The standard for water in stainless is 316.  Stress corrosion cracking  by chloride would be possible at about 180 F. Various threshold cracking temperatures can be found in literature from 150 F to 220 F. Alkaline water pH like above 8 would make it crack resistant.

Comment: Stress corrosion cracking of austenitic stainless in "very little chlorine"  provides job security for metallurgists.

Comment: 3 atmospheres is 45 psi.  this is a large pressure for a big thin wall tank. Are you adding chlorine? There are other chemicals that may be better. What is the max temp ? Was wondering if some plastics may be a better option.

Comment: What do you mean "can't be replaced?" That seems highly unlikely. Your whole house can be replaced... If you want to homebrew a tank, you homebrew an unpressurized tank and use a heat exchanger to move heat to the pressurized water system. If you want a pressurized tank, you buy one that's been properly engineered and tested.

Comment: I know in commercial occupancy’s anything above 1 atmosphere has to be certified, and requires inspection every 5-10 years depending on classification (some more often for boilers). residential may get away with A TPR valve but it would depend on the actual peak temp and pressure.

Comment: If the copper tank can't be replaced, what are you planning on doing with the stainless steel one?

Answer (score 4):

### NO. Pressure vessels must be certified!

This is not a thing to DIY because the destructive force can be considerable when it fails.

If the tank is not accessible for service or replacement, then somebody messed up.  There is a trend lately where people love to cover up all utilities with drywall or other "finish" treatments, rendering the utilities inaccessible. Don't do that. And if you did it, undo it or make the finish materials removable panels.